# Workstation sink

Tags: dishwasher, install

Most of the new workstation sinks don’t have a knockout for air gap and don’t accommodate a disposal… what’s the best solution for dishwasher venting?

Comment: I believe this question could be improved with evidence that "most" new workstation sinks are not disposal/air-gap compatible, or information that makes available disposal/air-gap compatible workstation sinks not suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Some "workstation sinks" on sale now do have disposal-compatible sink holes and an extra top hole for an air gap. I did a web-search on "workstation sink" and found plenty of kitchen sinks at Home Depot. One is this (no endorsement implied, only to show they exist on sale now):

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-AIO-33-in-Drop-in-Undermount-Single-Bowl-18-Gauge-Stainless-Steel-Workstation-Kitchen-Sink-with-Faucet-Cutting-Board-4332F/318258381#overlay

[image: Workstation sink with disposal drain and air gap hole]

This is from the above sink's [instruction manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/7c/7c95129f-66ed-4440-800b-8028c96f3d91.pdf) showing the typical 4" to ~2" drain adapter that can be taken out and replaced with the disposal adapter:
[image: workstation drain disposal insert from instruction manual]

Answer (score 1):

*a knockout for air gap*

Many dishwashers can use a high hose loop instead of a traditional air gap. That is easier to install and avoids the ugly air gap cover. However, if local code does not allow for a high hose loop then you can drill a hole to install the air gap.

In the opposite scenario, if you have an air gap for a dishwasher and get a new dishwasher that can use a high hose loop instead, you can install a soap dispenser using the old air gap hole.